# Historical reason behind different line ending at different platforms

Tags: operating-system, history, text-files, line-endings, eol

Why did DOS/Windows and Mac decide to use \r\n and \r for line ending instead of \n? Was it just a result of trying to be "different" from Unix?

And now that Mac OS X is Unix (-like), did Apple switch to \n from \r?

Comment: Waddya wanna bet it has something to do with line printers, and/or typewriters.

Comment: yeah but why do they STILL have different line endings? Very annoying compatibility issue that could be solved very easily.

Comment: MS finally fixes NotePad..... https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/05/08/extended-eol-in-notepad/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

DOS inherited CR-LF line endings (what you're calling \r\n, just making the ascii characters explicit) from CP/M.  CP/M inherited it from the various DEC operating systems which influenced CP/M designer Gary Kildall.

CR-LF was used so that the teletype machines would return the print head to the left margin (CR = carriage return), and then move to the next line (LF = line feed).

The Unix guys handled that in the device driver, and when necessary translated LF to CR-LF on output to devices that needed it.

And as you guessed, Mac OS X now uses LF.

Answer (score 23):

Really adding to @Mark Harrison...

The people who tell you that Unix is "just outputting the text the programmer specified" whereas DOS is broken are plain wrong. There are also claims that it's stupid for DOS to flag EOF when it sees an EOF character, raising the question of what exactly that EOF character is for.

There is no one true convention for text file line endings - only platform-specific conventions. After all, even CR-LF, CR and LF aren't the only line end conventions to ever be used, and ASCII was never even the one and only character set. The problem is the C standard library and runtime, which didn't abstract away this platform-dependent detail. Other third generation languages (such as Pascal and even Basic) managed it, at least to some degree. Because of this, when C compilers were written for other platforms, runtime library hacks were needed to achieve compatibility with existing source code and books.

In fact, it's Unix and Multics that originally needed string translation for console I/O, since users usually sat at an ASCII terminal that required CR LF line ends. This translation was done in a device driver, though - the goal was to abstract away the device-specifics, assuming that it was better to adopt one convention and stick to it for stored text files.

The C text I/O hack is similar in principle to what CygWin does now, hacking Linux runtimes to work as well as can be expected on Windows. There's a real history of hacking things about to turn them into Unix-alikes - but then there's also Wine, turning Linux into Windows. Oddly enough, you can read some misplaced line-end criticism of Windows in the [CygWin FAQ](http://web.archive.org/web/20100117052820/http://cygwin.com/faq/faq-nochunks.html#faq.api.cr-lf) (Internet Archive link added 2013 - the page no longer exists). Maybe it's just their sense of humour, since they are basically doing what they are criticising, but on a much grander scale ;-)

<strike>The C++ standard library (whatever platform its implemented on) avoids this issue using iostreams, which abstract away line ends.</strike> For output, that suits me fine. For input, I need more control, so I either interpret character-by-character or else use a scanner generator.

[**EDIT**  It turns out that the struck-out claim above isn't true, and never was. The `std::endl` literally translates to a `\n` and a flush. The `\n` is exactly the same `\n` you get in C - it tends to get called "new line", but it's actually an ASCII line feed character, which then gets translated by the runtime if necessary. Funny how false assumptions can get so ingrained you never question them - basically, C++ had no choice to do what C did (other than adding more layers on top) for compatibility reasons, and that should always have been obvious.]

The biggest slice of blame from my POV is with C, but C isn't the only project to fail to anticipate its move to other platforms. Blaming Bill Gates is just nuts - all he did was buy and polish a variant of the then popular CP/M. Really, it's just history - the same reason why we don't know what character codes 128 to 255 refer to in most text files. Given the ease of coping with all three line end conventions, it's odd that some developers still insist on that "my platforms convention is the one true way, and I shall force it on you like it or not" attitude.

Also - will the Unicode line separator codepoint U+2028 replace all these conventions in future text files? ;-)

Answer (score 9):

It's interesting to note the CRLF is pretty much the internet standard. That is, pretty much every standard internet protocol that is line oriented uses CRLF. SMTP, POP, IMAP, NNTP, etc.. The body of email consists of lines terminated by CRLF.

Comment: I'm curious, is it possible to back this claim somehow? It would make it more believable in my view.

Comment: @Fred:  Just check the RFCs that define the protocols.  For example, RFC 2616, which defines HTTP 1.1, specifies that the line separator for the headers is CR+LF.  (The payload line separator for certain content types may be interpreted more liberally, but even many of those are officially CR+LF.)  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-2.2

Comment: A lot of the original work on "the internet" was done on DEC computers, I know.  But I am surprised by this little fact, since it seems most of those were running UNIX.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia: in the beginning, the program had to put in extra CR characters before the LF to slow the program down so the printer had time to keep up - and CP/M and then later Windows used this method.  But Multics's printer driver put in extra characters automatically so the program didn't have to - and Unix developer from that.  But none of that explains why the early Mac didn't do that (they do now that they are based on Unix).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#History:

> The sequence CR+LF was commonly used on many early computer systems that had adopted Teletype machines—typically a Teletype Model 33 ASR—as a console device, because this sequence was required to position those printers at the start of a new line. The separation of newline into two functions concealed the fact that the print head could not return from the far right to the beginning of the next line in time to print the next character. Any character printed after a CR would often print as a smudge in the middle of the page while the print head was still moving the carriage back to the first position. "The solution was to make the newline two characters: CR to move the carriage to column one, and LF to move the paper up."[1] In fact, it was often necessary to send extra characters—extraneous CRs or NULs—which are ignored but give the print head time to move to the left margin. Many early video displays also required multiple character times to scroll the display.
>
> On such systems, applications had to talk directly to the Teletype machine and follow its conventions since the concept of device drivers hiding such hardware details from the application was not yet well developed. Therefore, text was routinely composed to satisfy the needs of Teletype machines. Most minicomputer systems from DEC used this convention. CP/M also used it in order to print on the same terminals that minicomputers used. From there MS-DOS (1981) adopted CP/M's CR+LF in order to be compatible, and this convention was inherited by Microsoft's later Windows operating system.
>
> The Multics operating system began development in 1964 and used LF alone as its newline. Multics used a device driver to translate this character to whatever sequence a printer needed (including extra padding characters), and the single byte was more convenient for programming. What seems like a more obvious[citation needed] choice—CR—was not used, as CR provided the useful function of overprinting one line with another to create boldface and strikethrough effects. Perhaps more importantly, the use of LF alone as a line terminator had already been incorporated into drafts of the eventual ISO/IEC 646 standard. Unix followed the Multics practice, and later Unix-like systems followed Unix. This created conflicts between Windows and Unix-like OSes, whereby files composed on one OS cannot be properly formatted or interpreted by another OS (for example a UNIX shell script written in a Windows text editor like Notepad).