# why fgets not work?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, fgets

I installed a new version of os X (10.7 initially and then updated to 10.7.5) - I lost man fgets in Terminal, it no longer exists(not olny fgets, some other too). I'm using xcode 4.6.3, updated all kinds of documentation. In documentation i got only FGETS(3), not fgets!
When i write this code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE *wordFile = fopen ("/tmp/words.txt", "r");
    char word[100];
    while (fgets(word, 100, wordFile))
    {
        word[strlen(word) - 1] = '\0';          // strip off the trailing \n
        NSLog (@"%s is %lu characters long", word, strlen(word));
    }

    fclose (wordFile);
    return 0;
}
```

i got output:

```
Joe-Bob "Handyman" Brown
Jacksonville "Sly" Murphy
Shinara Bain
George "Guitar" Book is 84 characters long
```

Why?

Comment: Note: strlen() _can_ return zero.

Comment: So, what is your question? The string you posted is indeed 84 characters long. The program says it is 84 characters long. Where's the problem? What "does not work"?

Comment: in txt file string got every name on new line (4 lines) then i copy it there - it too look like 1 line, but I copy 4 lines!!!

Comment: @dvsvvsdvsvs The reason your output text is being reflowed onto one line is that you haven't inserted formatting marks to indicate that it shouldn't. Edit the question, and insert four spaces at the beginning of each of those lines.

Comment: http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/

Comment: Perhaps the lines in the file are separated by *carriage return* (0x0d) instead of *line feed* (0x0a) ?

Comment: @dvsv vsdvsvs Maybe the file was created using OS9 code (used '\r' as end-of-line) and now you have a new OS which generally uses '\n', maybe including the compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My money on @Martin R.

`fgets()` did not find a converted `\n` in file "/tmp/words.txt" even though it was open in text mode "t".  The editor used to create/edit the file is ending the lines with `\r`.

See @Michael Haren in [Do line endings differ between Windows and Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426397/do-line-endings-differ-between-windows-and-linux)

BTW: word[strlen(word) - 1] = '\0'; is potentially a problem, though not in this case, as `strlen(word)` may be 0.  (@wildplasser)

Comment: `word[strlen(word) - 1]` is *not* a problem, because fgets() returns NULL if no character was read at all, and the loop terminates in that case.

Comment: @Martin R  Buffer filled by `fgets()` may have a _string_ length of 0.  `fgets()` fills until  a `\n`: "No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained)" C11dr 7.21.7.2 `strlen()` counts until a `\0`. This difference is problematic in rare cases when a file has `\n` followed by `\0`. `fgets()` reads up to `\n`.  The next `fgets()` reads in `\0` ...  into the buffer, appending a '\0'.  The `strlen("\0...\n") returns 0 and `buf[strlen(buf)-1]` is UB.  This problem is rare in stdin as usually takes a piped input to generate, more likely in files likes OP's case.

Comment: You are right, I did not think of that situation.