# Cant open file using c_str() in linux

Tags: c++, linux, file, fstream

On Windows, I have no problems opening the file from string.  On Linux (where it needs to work) I can't open the file.

```
    string name;

//open 1st file, with the next file name - this works
fstream file( "data.dat", ios::in);

if(file.good()){
    getline(file, name);

            //some code here

    file.close();
}else{
    return 1;
}


    // this here does not work
fstream file1(name.c_str() , ios::in);
if(file1.good()){

    //some code here

    file1.close();
}else{
    cout<<"can't open file"<<endl;
    return 1;
}
```

If instead `name.c_str()` I write the file name directly it works, but every try on getting the name from the file ended with the file not opening.

I've tried creating const char* from name, doesn't work too.

Comment: Have you actually set `name` to a sensible value? Have you checked with the debugger?

Comment: So you probably aren't reading what you think you are.  Maybe spaces or what not.  Use a debugger or print out what is in name.

Comment: Are you aware that filenames in Linux are case-sensitive?

Comment: Everything points to `name` not having the value you expect. Have you checked, how did you check?

Comment: @Eric Finn yes I'm aware of that, everything is in lowercase the file name too.

Comment: @john @Duck in `name` I have `dane.txt` the file name and ofc I've checked it so it has just that string. So it seems to point into the right thing. And as I wrote earlier variable `name` works in windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file probably has [Windows-style line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426397). Either sanitise the file, or check for and remove any carriage-return character, `\r`, at the end of each line.

Comment: Isn't `getline` in ASCII mode supposed to translate and then strip those (well, the underlying buffer does the translating)?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It will translate the host representation of end-of-line into `\n`. A Windows implementation will strip the `\r`, but a Linux implementation won't.

Comment: @MikeSeymour This was indeed the case. Creating new `data.dat` file in linux solved the whole problem.