# File difference between Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows

I explore a source code of some programm and stumbled with:

```
// remove newlines and partial newlines to help fix issues with Windows formatted config files on Linux systems

            Line.erase( remove( Line.begin( ), Line.end( ), '\r' ), Line.end( ) );
            Line.erase( remove( Line.begin( ), Line.end( ), '\n' ), Line.end( ) );
```

What does it mean?

Comment: [About newline in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Comment: A simple google search would have yielded enough responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physically, different systems represent the new line character
in a text file differently.  This can sometimes cause
difficulties when the file was written on one system, and is
being read on another.  In most cases, a file written as text on
one system will not even be readable on another system.  The
major exceptions are Windows and Unix (and Mac OS, too, I think,
even before it was Unix), however; on all of these systems,
files are just a sequence of bytes, and each system, by
convention, uses a simple sequence of one or two characters to
represent a line end (or line separator---the convention isn't
clear under Windows).  If these are the only systems targetted
(and that's true for a lot of programs), then it's possible to
read the file, separated into lines, but you may get some extra 
characters in the lines (most typically, and additional `'\r\`
at the end of every line when reading under Unix if the file was
written under Windows).  The code you cite is just trying to
remove these characters, in an extremely overly cautious manner.

Answer (score 1):

The line ending in unix and windows are different. This thing is done to use the suitable line ending in a specific system. You may see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426397/do-line-endings-differ-between-windows-and-linux) to know what line ending is.