# Regex problem searching through a pyperclip multipleline copied text

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, newline, pyperclip

Happens to me a rare thing when trying to do a search with regex trough a `pyperclip.paste()` if the search expression involves a `\n` new line character.

Excuse my English.

When the search, I make it trough this triple quote assigned to a `text` variable:

```
import re

text = '''
This as the line 1
This as the line 2
'''

pattern = re.compile(r'\d\n\w+')
result = pattern.findall(text)
print(result)
```

It actually prints the new line character `\n`. Which is what I want, or almost what I expect.

> »»» ['1\nThis']

But the problem starts when the string to search come from a text copied from the clipboard.

```
This as the line 1
This as the line 2
```

Say I just select and copy to clipboard that text and i want regex to extract the same previous output from it.
This time I need to use pyperclip module.

So, forgetting the previous code and write this instead:

```
import re, pyperclip

text = pyperclip.paste()

pattern = re.compile(r'\d\n\w+')
result = pattern.findall(text)
print(result)
```

This is the result:

> »»» [ ]

Nothing but two brackets. I discover (in my inexperience) that the problem causing this is the `\n` character. And it has nothing to do with a conflict between the python (also \n character), because we avoid that with 'r'.

I already found a not too clearly solution for this (for me almost, because I'm just with the basics of Python right now).

```
import re, pyperclip

text = pyperclip.paste()
lines = text.split('\n')
spam = ''

for i in lines:
    spam = spam + i

pattern = re.compile(r'\d\r\w+')
result = pattern.findall(spam)
print(result)
```

Note that instead of `\n` for detect *new lines* in the last regex expression, I opted to `\r` (`\n` would cause the same bad behavior printing only brackets).
`\r` its exchangeable with `\s`, the output works, but:

> »»» ['1\rThis']

With `\r` instead of `\n`

At least it was a little victory for me.

It'll helps me a lot if you could explain to me a better solution for this o almost understand why this happened. You also can recommend me some concepts to investigate to, for a fully comprehension of this.

Comment: You can use `\d\r?\n\w+` to deal with line breaks where the `\r` may or may not be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the `\r` when pasting is because you are pasting from a Windows machine.  On windows, the newline characters are represented by `\r\n`. Note that `\s` is different from `\r`. `\s` means any whitespace characters. `\r` is only the carriage return character.

The text:

`This as the line 1
This as the line 2`

actually looks like:

`This as the line 1\r\n
This as the line 2\r\n`

on a windows machine.

In the regex, the`\d\r` matches to end of the first line:  `1\r` but then the `\w+` doesn't match the `\n`.  You need to edit your first regex to be:

`pattern = re.compile(r'\d\r\n\w+')`

Source: [Do line endings differ between Windows and Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426397/do-line-endings-differ-between-windows-and-linux)