# TypeScript : Not being able to iterate line by line over a uploaded file(Angular 9)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9

I want to iterate line by line over a user uploaded file in my Angular app. I have tried the approach stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55218064/typescript-angular-read-text-file-line-by-line) but I get the following error:

> core.js:6260 ERROR TypeError: this.firstfile.split is not a function
>   or its return value is not iterable
>       at AppComponent.firstfileupload (app.component.ts:23)
>       at AppComponent_Template_input_change_2_listener (app.component.html:2)
>       at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:21815)
>       at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:21857)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (platform-browser.js:976)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41640)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
>       at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:480)

My code for `app.component.ts`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  firstfile=null;
  second_file = null;
  title = 'first';

  constructor(private http:HttpClient){

  }

  firstfileupload(event){
    console.log("First file")
    console.log(event)
    this.firstfile=event.target.files[0]
    for(const line of this.firstfile.split(/[\r\n]+/)){
      console.log(line)
    }
    console.log("First file File has been changed")
  }
  secondfile(event){
    this.second_file=event.target.files[0];
    // for(const line of this.second_file.split(/[\r\n]+/)){
    //   console.log(line)
    // }
    console.log("Second file uploaded")
  }
  onUpload(){
    console.log("Upload button clicked")
    // const fd = new FormData();
    // fd.append('files',this.firstfile);
    // fd.append('files',this.second_file);
    // this.http.post('http://localhost:5000',fd).subscribe(res =>{
    //   console.log(res)
    // }

    // )
  }
}
```

And for `app.component.html`

```js
<h1>Upload the files</h1>
<input type="file" (change)="firstfileupload($event)">
<input type="file" (change)="secondfile($event)">
<button type="button" (click)="onUpload()">Upload</button>
```

How can I iterate over an uploaded file ? I would rather not save the file and just iterate there only. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - Read a file and parse its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581687/angular-read-a-file-and-parse-its-content)

Comment: My question is a bit different. Thanks for feedback

Comment: The answer is exactly the same though....

Comment: I think the answer here gives much more clarity and better implementation, than the one over there. However, if you still want to close this, you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to read the contents of the file using [`FileReader.readAsText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText). Try the following

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

export class AppComponent {
  ...

  firstfileupload(event) {
    this.firstfile = event.currentTarget.files[0];

    this.readFileContent(event.currentTarget.files[0]).subscribe(
      content => {
        for(const line of content.split(/[\r\n]+/)) {
          if (line !== '') {          // <-- regex pattern might return an empty line at the EOF
            console.log(line);
          }
        }
      }
    );

    console.log("First file File has been changed")
  }

  private readFileContent(file): Observable<any> {
    let result = new Subject<any>();           // <-- Step 1: Create an empty RxJS `Subject`

    const reader = new FileReader();           // <-- Step 2: Create a `FileReader` object
    reader.onload = (e) => {                   // <-- Step 5: Callback function to trigger on the evnet `onload`
      const fileContent = e.target.result;     // <-- Step 6: `event.target.result` contains the file content
      result.next(fileContent);                // <-- Step 7: Push the file contents to the `result` subject
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);                   // <-- Step 3: Read the file using `FileReader`'s method `readAsText`

    return result.asObservable();              // <-- Step 4: Return the `result` subject
  }
}
```

The `FileReader` is part of the `File API`. It contains the following [events](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-readAsText) that are triggered based on their respective actions.

```
+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Event name | Fired when…                                                    |
+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| loadstart  | When the read starts.                                          |
| progress   | While reading (and decoding) blob                              |
| abort      | When the read has been aborted.                                |
|            | For instance, by invoking the abort() method.                  |
| error      | When the read has failed (see file read errors).               |
| load       | When the read has successfully completed.                      |
| loadend    | When the request has completed (either in success or failure). |
+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

We are creating the object and reading the contents of the file using the callback function to the `load` event. Since the data handling is asynchronous, we use a RxJS Subject to read the data returned from the function `readFileContent` asynchronously.

You could learn more about asynchronous data here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6513921

Comment: But can you explain your code a bit more to me ? That `readFileContent` I didn't understand, if you could explain or refer me to some tutorial so that I can understand it more better , that would help me a lot.

Comment: I've added some explanation inline and attached some sources.

Comment: Can you refer me to some link where I can learn how to display the contents of a file ?

Answer (score 0):

You problem, based on `this.firstfile.split is not a function or its return value is not iterable` error, is that you are trying to iterate an object (i.e., the file), not its contents.

```
firstfileupload(event){
    . . .
    this.firstfile=event.target.files[0]  // <<<----- You recover the file. As OBJECT
    for(const line of this.firstfile.split(/[\r\n]+/)){ // <<<--- You want to iterate the OBJECT like it is an STRING element
      . . .
    }
    . . .
  }
```

You need to use the `FileReader` helper to iterate file contents.

Check this: [Angular - Read a file and parse its content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581687/angular-read-a-file-and-parse-its-content)