# New line is not recognized on different computer

Tags: javascript, readfile, readline, testcomplete

I'm using Javascript (specifically in TestComplete) to read a file. On one computer, this works exactly as I expect it to and each line is printed individually. On a different computer using the exact same XML file, this is all read as one line. It prints with line breaks, just the entire file in one single print. The line breaks are CR+LF.

```
var settingsPath = Project.Path + "Supporting Files\\Settings.xml"
var settingsFile = aqFile.OpenTextFile(settingsPath, aqFile.faRead, aqFile.ctUTF8)

// Read the settings file.
while (!settingsFile.IsEndOfFile()) {
    var line = settingsFile.ReadLine()
    Log.Message(line)
}
```

Why would it read the file differently between different computers, and how can I fix this?

Comment: (Why would you read _XML_ line-by-line to begin with?)

Comment: Some lines need to be replaced, and TestComplete is really picky with how it writes XML files. So I just read it as if it's a text file then write the changes back out.

Answer (score 0):

Are the two different computers running two different operating systems, i.e. Windows and Linux? Windows and Linux handle line breaks differently.

[Do line endings differ between Windows and Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426397/do-line-endings-differ-between-windows-and-linux)

Comment: Both computers are running Windows 10. The file is being pulled using git.

Comment: Yeah, that would be too easy. According to https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/scripting/specifics/javascript.html, 'TestComplete is powered by V8 engine v. 5.8. ' All other things (i.e. OS) being equal, a version mismatch in the TestComplete Javascript engine might account for non-identical output.