# How can I concatenate string in loop in linux bash?

Tags: linux, string, bash

I am new on coding in bash Linux and I have the following problem.

I'm trying to concatenate string in loop to create a path. I have a text file in which I stored some strings to use in the loop. I wrote this example just to show you the problem:

```
for bio in `cat /data/giordano/species_ranges/prova_bio.txt` # list of strings: "bio_01", "bio_02"...
do
echo  /data/giordano/species_range/$bio.tif # concatenation
done
```

The result I expect would be:

```
/data/giordano/species_range/bio_01.tif
/data/giordano/species_range/bio_02.tif
/data/giordano/species_range/bio_03.tif
```

But what actually came out was:

```
.tifa/giordano/species_range/bio_01
.tifa/giordano/species_range/bio_02
.tifa/giordano/species_range/bio_03
/data/giordano/species_range/bio_04.tif
```

I really don't understand what kind of problem it is...

Comment: Looks like you have carriage return characters in your file's line endings. Did you maybe create it on Windows?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/803162/how-to-change-windows-line-ending-to-unix-version

Comment: ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) has a bunch of options for dealing with Windows line endings. Also, [don't read lines with `for`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor); use a `while read` loop instead (see [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), and BTW `while IFS=$'\r' read ...` is one way to fix Windows line endings). Finally: use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) to spot common scripting mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have [Windows line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426404/3018229) in your file, which contain an additional carriage return (`\r`). This makes the cursor go to the beginning of the line. You can remove the `\r`s from your file by [piping](https://www.howtogeek.com/438882/how-to-use-pipes-on-linux/) to [`tr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr). Extend your first line like this:

```sh
for bio in `cat /data/giordano/species_ranges/prova_bio.txt | tr -d '\r'`
```

Comment: However, one shouldn't use `for line in $(cat file)` at all in the first place; see [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: ...if one switches to a [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop, making it ignore `\r`s doesn't require `tr` at all: `while IFS=$'\r' read -r bio; do ...; done </path/to/prova_bio.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that awk would be simpler for this task. We use tr to remove the Cr line endings

```
~/tests/bash $ tr -d "\r" < data/giordano/species_range/proverbio.txt | awk '{ print "/data/giordano/species_range/" $0 ".tif"
> }'
/data/giordano/species_range/bio_1.tif
/data/giordano/species_range/bio_2.tif
/data/giordano/species_range/bio_3.tif
/data/giordano/species_range/bio_4.tif
```

Thank you to Charles Duffy for the improvements.