# How to count spaces and pass characters or newline?

Tags: c, string, algorithm, char

I was writing a tool that replaces enough spaces with tab,
but it counts more spaces than expected.

Algorithm should count spaces until seeing character or
newline, if there is a character or newline, it passes to next
element of string; but unfortunately continues to count spaces instead
of passing newline or character.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

int set_tab_init_arg(char *filename, int space_size)
{
        struct stat filest;
        FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r+");
        int fd = fileno(fp);
        int line = 0, space = 0, var = 0, offset = 0;

        if (fstat(fd, &filest) < 0)
                return -1;

        char *filecontent = (char*)malloc(filest.st_size);
        char buff[BUFFER_SIZE];

        if (fp == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "cyntax: invalid file pointer!\n");
                return -1;
        }

        while (fgets(buff, BUFFER_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
                strcat(filecontent, buff);

        char *tmpcontent, *willbewrited = filecontent;

        for (int x = 0; x < strlen(filecontent); x++) {
                if (filecontent[x] == 32) { 
                        printf("space\n"); 
                        space++; 
                }

                else if (filecontent[x++] == 10) { 
                        line++; 
                        printf("newline: %d\n", line); 
                        space = 0; 
                }

                else {
                        printf("char\n");
                        x++;
                        var++;
                }

                if (space == space_size) {
                        replace_spaces_to_tab();
                        printf("space = space_size\n");
                }

                filecontent++, offset++;
        }
}
```

here is file I tested on:

```
 a
 b
 c
 d
 e f g
 c h e
 p ğ a
```

and debug result is here (stdout):

```
space
newline: 1
newline: 2
newline: 3
newline: 4
space
space
space = space_size
newline: 5
space
space
space = space_size
newline: 6
space
char
```

I executed with parameters:
`./cyntax try -t 2`

Note-1: `try` is file and `-t 2` gets space size for converting enough spaces to tab.

Note-2: I used printf() function for debugging.

Comment: On a quick look through your code, I see what appears to be rather too many occurrences of `x++` in and around the `for` loop. I can't see why that should be anywhere except as the terminal statement of the loop itself.

Comment: Wait a minute, I thought I must increment x for passing elements, now it looks like it doesn't make sense.

Comment: The loop control will increment `x` sufficiently. After the `x++` when another character is found, the loop's will then skip a character.

Comment: Now I removed increments that doesn't make sense, but result looks same.

Comment: This seems to replace greedily . . . typically, it is more complicated because there are tab stops; that is, each tab is a variable number of spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problems were created by:

- incrementing x additionally in the for loop  `x++;` ( I believe this was already fixed in the comments)
- incrementing the filecontent pointer at the end of your for loop `filecontent++;`

I code on linux. That's why I had to change your line break detection slightly. ([Do line endings differ between Windows and Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426397/do-line-endings-differ-between-windows-and-linux)). not relevant to your problem though...

### My Solution

I markes my changes with  `CHANGE::`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

int set_tab_init_arg(char *filename, int space_size)
{
        struct stat filest;
        FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r+");
        int fd = fileno(fp);
        int line = 0, space = 0, var = 0, offset = 0;

        if (fstat(fd, &filest) < 0)
                return -1;

        char *filecontent = (char*)malloc(filest.st_size);
        char buff[BUFFER_SIZE];

        if (fp == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "cyntax: invalid file pointer!\n");
                return -1;
        }

        while (fgets(buff, BUFFER_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
                strcat(filecontent, buff);

        char *tmpcontent, *willbewrited = filecontent;

        for (int x = 0; x < strlen(filecontent); x++) {
                if (filecontent[x] == 32) { 
                        printf("space\n"); 
                        space++; 
                }

                else if (filecontent[x] == 10) { // CHANGE:: on linux. for windows filcontent[x++] is right :)
                        line++; 
                        printf("newline: %d\n", line); 
                        space = 0; 
                }

                else {
                        printf("char\n");
                        //x++; //CHANGE:: removed else you would skip after chars
                        var++;
            space = 0;
                }

                if (space == space_size) {
                       // replace_spaces_to_tab(); //CHANGE:: commented just to be able to compile
                        printf("space = space_size\n");
                }

               // filecontent++; //CHANGE:: removed else you would skip chars
            offset++;
        }
}

//CHANGE:: needed a main...
int main(){


set_tab_init_arg("try",2 );

}
```

compiled with gcc on linux fedora:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -o a.out main.c
```

testfile:

```
 a
 b
 c
 d
 e f g
 c h e
 p ğ a
```

my output to your testfile:

```
% ./a.out                             
space
char
newline: 1
space
char
newline: 2
space
char
newline: 3
space
char
newline: 4
space
char
space
char
space
char
newline: 5
space
char
space
char
space
char
newline: 6
space
char
space
char
char
space
char
newline: 7
```