# Python: incorrect os.linesep on OS X

Tags: python, pyqt4, osx-mountain-lion, eol

Platform: OS X Mountain Lion

Python 2.7.4

I have a piece of script that needs to convert all eol characters in a string to unix style \n.
I get a string supplied by Qsci.Scintilla.text() referenced to below as txt.

```
print 'original text: %s' % repr(unicode(txt))
print 'linesep: %s' % repr(os.linesep)
print 'fixed text: %s' % repr(unicode(txt).replace(os.linesep, '\n'))
```

This shows output like:

```
original text: u'exp.cnvs.show()\rself.sleep(1000)'
linesep: '\n'
fixed text: u'exp.cnvs.show()\rself.sleep(1000)'
```

All eol characters in there are reported as \r (which is correct for OS X af far as I know). Still os.linesep reports \n to be the eol character, causing the bottom statement to do nothing. The output of that statement of course should have been:

```
fixed text: u'exp.cnvs.show()\nself.sleep(1000)'
```

Does anyone know why os.linesep appears to report the wrong eol character on OSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `\r` (carriage return, or `CR`) is only correct for *old* Mac OS, so up to release 9.

OS X is a complete rewrite, and now a UNIX-based OS. It uses `\n` (line feed, or `LF`).

From [Wikipedia on the subject of Newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations):

> - `LF`:    Multics, Unix and Unix-like systems (GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, AIX, Xenix, etc.), BeOS, Amiga, RISC OS and others.
>
> [...]
>
> - `CR`:    Commodore 8-bit machines, Acorn BBC, ZX Spectrum, TRS-80, Apple II family, Mac OS up to version 9 and OS-9

See [Historical reason behind different line ending at different platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419291/historical-reason-behind-different-line-ending-at-different-platforms) for some history behind this.

Instead, it's Scintilla that is in the wrong here. The [Line endings documenation](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#LineEndings) suggests it defaults to `\r` when on Mac:

> Scintilla can interpret any of the Macintosh (`\r`), Unix (`\n`) and Windows (`\r\n`) line ends.

You can use the [`SCI_SETEOLMODE()` function](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_SETEOLMODE) to alter that behaviour, whatever the Python binding equivalent is should be passed the `os.linesep` value to make Scintilla use the correct line separator for your platform.

I see that there is a [`QsciScintilla.setEolMode()` method](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciScintilla.html#a0f2353468d2c37abe9c933d4ac0478ad) and a [`EOLMode` enum](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/QScintilla2/classQsciScintilla.html#ab4b6b4286a74e173a86de0a7f55241d5) to accomplish that; I guess you'll need to map python line ending variants to the enum and pass the right enum value to the `.setEolMode()` method.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Why would Qscintilla then still return the text with a \r as the newline character?

Comment: @DanielS: Perhaps that's a bug in Qscintilla?

Comment: @DanielS: Ah, Scintilla is rather dated; the [documentation I found](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#LineEndings) indeed suggests `\r` is used regardless of Mac OS version. Setting `SCI_SETEOLMODE` to `os.linesep` seems to be a good work-around.

Comment: Thanks! I found the documentation on the SCI EOL methods and it appears to work fine! Strange that QScintilla upholds these old standards, but it least it can be solved.