# Reading csv from FTP folder

Tags: python, ftp

I am trying to read csv file from FTP Folder

```
ftp = FTP('adr')  
ftp.login(user='xxxx', passwd = 'xxxxx')
r = StringIO()
ftp.retrbinary('RETR /DataLoadFolder/xxx/xxx/xxx/'+str(file_name),r.write)
r.seek(0)
csvfile1 = csv.reader(r,delimiter=';')
input_file = [list(line) for line in csv.reader(r)] ----- Error
```

getting an error at last line as

```
new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

My csv file

[image]

Text Version
[image]

There are whites spaces at the end of each row (after 17.00)

Data starts from second row

what does the error mean? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A csv file is **not** a spreadsheet but plain text. Once you load it into Excel, what you see in not the original file but the way it has been transformed. Please show the text version...

Comment: @SergeBallesta edited question and added text version. FYI there are around 70 white spaces at the end of each row

Comment: How can you feed a `StringIO` with bytes retrieved from `retrbinary`? Is this really your real code?

Answer (score 1):

The error message simply asking how you'd want to handle the newline differently due to historical reasons, you can read the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419460/4902099).

To solve the issue, specify the `newline` on `StringIO` like this:

```
r = StringIO(newline='')
```

According to [StringIO documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO). If newline is set to None, newlines are written as `\n` on all platforms, but universal newline decoding is still performed when reading.

Comment: nothing seems to be worked. please find edited question. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should test the code by reading the csv directly from file to make sure whether the StringIO/FTP reading cause the problem or the problem was caused by malformed csv file.

Comment: problem was caused by malformed csv file, previously i used to read csv firectly from  file with same code.

Answer (score 1):

I could partially reproduce and fix. The error is caused by a line containing a *bad* end of line. I could reproduce by adding a line `\r \n` at the end of an otherway valid csv file.

A simple way to fix it is to use a filter to eliminate blank lines and clean end of lines:

```
def filter_bytes(fd):
    for line in fd:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) != 0:
            yield(line + b'\r\n')
```

Once this is done, your code could become:

```
ftp = FTP('adr')  
ftp.login(user='xxxx', passwd = 'xxxxx')
r = BytesIO()
ftp.retrbinary('RETR /DataLoadFolder/xxx/xxx/xxx/'+str(file_name),r.write)
r.seek(0)
csvfile1 = csv.reader(filter_bytes(r),delimiter=';')
input_file = list(csvfile1)
```